# Jenkins pipeline exit code 137: maven build fails at sonarqube analysis

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, sonarqube

After upgrading our ***SonarQube Server from 6.3 to 6.5*** we are experiencing a weird issue with some of our build pipelines (I'm not sure if the upgrade actually caused this issue but it was after the upgrade that we first noticed. this does not happen in all projects).

During the SonarQube analysis, all of the servers memory and swap is filling up, the jenkins pipeline then fails with error code 137. Console output shows this error message:

---

```
/home/jenkins/workspace/SP_wspadaptorservice_master-DJJLS64T4TWKICWSK3LOTAQTPHHR7GDJ5O3T7PFUUHASLVSDJPQQ@tmp/withMavenb0f23023/mvn: line 3: 100318 Killed
/home/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/M3/bin/mvn --global-settings /home/jenkins/workspace/SP_wspadaptorservice_master-DJJLS64T4TWKICWSK3LOTAQTPHHR7GDJ5O3T7PFUUHASLVSDJPQQ@tmp/withMavenb0f23023/globalSettings.xml --batch-mode --show-version "$@"
ERROR: [withMaven] WARNING Exception parsing the logs generated by the Jenkins Maven Event Spy /home/jenkins/workspace/SP_wspadaptorservice_master-DJJLS64T4TWKICWSK3LOTAQTPHHR7GDJ5O3T7PFUUHASLVSDJPQQ@tmp/withMavenb0f23023/maven-spy-20170918-151032-313.log, ignore file.  Please report a bug associated for the component 'pipeline-maven-plugin' at https://issues.jenkins-ci.org 
ERROR: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 393; columnNumber: 201; XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
```

---

So obviously what we did first was increasing the memory and swap space of our VM, restarting the server and starting the build again.
This resulted in the now 20gb of memory gradually filling up, then 20gb of swap filling up before the build fails again, this takes about 2.5 minutes. I cannot imagine a build actually using this much memory.

*Setting -Xmx and -Xms in Jenkins' Global MAVEN_OPTS did not change this behavior.*

After looking online and in logs, upgrading all plugins, I really don't know where to tackle this issue from, and I'm sure I'm overlooking something. If you need any logs or more information I'm happy to provide.

I'm not sure if this is a problem with Jenkins, maven or sonarqube, so any input is greatly appreciated.

**Versions running:**

- Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo)
- Jenkins Version 2.73.1
- Maven Version 3.3.9 (also tried with 3.5.0, same result)
- SonarQube Version 6.5
- SonarJava Code Analyzer Version 4.13.0.11627
- OpenJDK Version 1.8

**Example of a failing pipeline** (Fails at post success of Stage 'Test'):

```
#!groovy
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                git credentialsId: 'xxx', url: 'yyy.git'
                checkout scm
            }
        }
        stage('Clean') {
            steps {
                withMaven(maven: 'M3') {
                    sh "mvn clean"
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                withMaven(maven: 'M3') {
                    sh "mvn test"
                }
            }
            post {
                success {
                    junit '**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
                    withMaven(maven: 'M3') {
                        sh "mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.branch=${BRANCH_NAME}"
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                withMaven(maven: 'M3') {
                    sh "mvn clean install"
                }
            }
            post {
                success {
                    archiveArtifacts artifacts: '**/target/*.war', fingerprint: true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Debug Output:**

```
[INFO] 17:12:03.363 Java Main Files AST scan
[INFO] 17:12:03.364 231 source files to be analyzed
[DEBUG] 17:12:03.389 'src/main/java/com/company/boundaries/AbstractImportScheduler.java' generated metadata  with charset 'UTF-8'
[DEBUG] 17:12:04.468 Could not complete symbolic execution: 
org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker$MaximumStepsReachedException: reached limit of 16000 steps for method processFileList#213 in class AbstractImportScheduler
    at org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker.throwMaxSteps(ExplodedGraphWalker.java:282)
    at org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker.execute(ExplodedGraphWalker.java:231)
    at org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker.visitMethod(ExplodedGraphWalker.java:204)
    at org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker.visitMethod(ExplodedGraphWalker.java:196)
    at org.sonar.java.se.SymbolicExecutionVisitor.execute(SymbolicExecutionVisitor.java:77)
    at org.sonar.java.se.SymbolicExecutionVisitor.visitNode(SymbolicExecutionVisitor.java:63)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:95)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:120)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:97)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:120)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:97)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.scanTree(SubscriptionVisitor.java:78)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.scanFile(SubscriptionVisitor.java:64)
    at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.visitFile(VisitorsBridge.java:114)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:96)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.scan(JavaAstScanner.java:68)
    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scanSources(JavaSquid.java:119)
    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scan(JavaSquid.java:113)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.execute(JavaSquidSensor.java:84)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:53)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:88)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:82)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:68)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:78)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:179)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:144)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:129)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:261)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:256)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:245)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:144)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:129)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:84)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:144)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:129)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:119)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:116)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:77)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute(SonarQubeMojo.java:139)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)

[DEBUG] 17:12:05.380 'src/main/java/com/company/boundaries/commons/AbstractExportScheduler.java' generated metadata  with charset 'UTF-8'
[DEBUG] 17:12:09.332 Could not complete symbolic execution: 
org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker$MaximumStepsReachedException: reached limit of 16000 steps for method startTimers#286 in class AbstractExportScheduler
    at org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker.throwMaxSteps(ExplodedGraphWalker.java:282)
    at org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker.execute(ExplodedGraphWalker.java:231)
    at org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker.visitMethod(ExplodedGraphWalker.java:204)
    at org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker.visitMethod(ExplodedGraphWalker.java:196)
    at org.sonar.java.se.SymbolicExecutionVisitor.execute(SymbolicExecutionVisitor.java:77)
    at org.sonar.java.se.SymbolicExecutionVisitor.visitNode(SymbolicExecutionVisitor.java:63)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:95)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:120)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:97)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:120)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:97)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.scanTree(SubscriptionVisitor.java:78)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.scanFile(SubscriptionVisitor.java:64)
    at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.visitFile(VisitorsBridge.java:114)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:96)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.scan(JavaAstScanner.java:68)
    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scanSources(JavaSquid.java:119)
    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scan(JavaSquid.java:113)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.execute(JavaSquidSensor.java:84)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:53)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:88)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:82)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:68)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:78)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:179)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:144)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:129)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:261)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:256)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:245)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:144)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:129)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:84)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:144)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:129)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:119)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:116)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:77)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute(SonarQubeMojo.java:139)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)

[DEBUG] 17:12:10.382 'src/main/java/com/company/boundaries/commons/AbstractNonSapScheduler.java' generated metadata  with charset 'UTF-8'
[DEBUG] 17:12:11.005 'src/main/java/com/company/boundaries/commons/ConfigChangeListener.java' generated metadata  with charset 'UTF-8'
[DEBUG] 17:12:12.209 'src/main/java/com/company/boundaries/nonsap/dataexport/CAScheduler.java' generated metadata  with charset 'UTF-8'
[DEBUG] 17:12:12.868 'src/main/java/com/company/boundaries/nonsap/dataexport/FRScheduler.java' generated metadata  with charset 'UTF-8'
[DEBUG] 17:12:13.176 'src/main/java/com/company/boundaries/nonsap/dataexport/SESafetyStockScheduler.java' generated metadata  with charset 'UTF-8'
[DEBUG] 17:12:13.380 'src/main/java/com/company/boundaries/nonsap/dataexport/SEScheduler.java' generated metadata  with charset 'UTF-8'
[INFO] 17:12:13.422 7/231 files analyzed, current file: /home/jenkins/workspace/torservice_temp_jenkinstest-JHGJFDJ3NKMRDAXZBOCEGNRKX2SUYVXPNSYOH4DAWJ7M6OZB7NFA/src/main/java/com/company/boundaries/nonsap/dataexport/SEScheduler.java
[DEBUG] 17:12:13.597 'src/main/java/com/company/boundaries/nonsap/dataimport/NonSapScheduler.java' generated metadata  with charset 'UTF-8'
[DEBUG] 17:12:15.105 'src/main/java/com/company/boundaries/sap/star/dataexport/ATScheduler.java' generated metadata  with charset 'UTF-8'
[DEBUG] 17:12:15.865 'src/main/java/com/company/boundaries/sap/star/dataexport/FEScheduler.java' generated metadata  with charset 'UTF-8'
[DEBUG] 17:12:18.478 'src/main/java/com/company/boundaries/sap/star/dataexport/FIScheduler.java' generated metadata  with charset 'UTF-8'
[DEBUG] 17:12:19.619 'src/main/java/com/company/boundaries/sap/star/dataexport/NOScheduler.java' generated metadata  with charset 'UTF-8'
[DEBUG] 17:12:20.134 'src/main/java/com/company/boundaries/sap/star/dataexport/WEScheduler.java' generated metadata  with charset 'UTF-8'
[DEBUG] 17:12:20.570 'src/main/java/com/company/boundaries/sap/star/dataimport/StarScheduler.java' generated metadata  with charset 'UTF-8'
[DEBUG] 17:12:21.390 'src/main/java/com/company/boundaries/sap/wint/dataexport/WintExportScheduler.java' generated metadata  with charset 'UTF-8'
[DEBUG] 17:12:22.055 'src/main/java/com/company/boundaries/sap/wint/dataimport/WintImportScheduler.java' generated metadata  with charset 'UTF-8'
[INFO] 17:12:23.422 16/231 files analyzed, current file: /home/jenkins/workspace/torservice_temp_jenkinstest-JHGJFDJ3NKMRDAXZBOCEGNRKX2SUYVXPNSYOH4DAWJ7M6OZB7NFA/src/main/java/com/company/boundaries/sap/wint/dataimport/WintImportScheduler.java
[DEBUG] 17:12:23.994 'src/main/java/com/company/boundaries/sap/wrp/dataexport/PTScheduler.java' generated metadata  with charset 'UTF-8'
[DEBUG] 17:12:25.022 'src/main/java/com/company/boundaries/sap/wrp/dataimport/WrpScheduler.java' generated metadata  with charset 'UTF-8'
[DEBUG] 17:12:29.528 'src/main/java/com/company/controls/DataExportController.java' generated metadata  with charset 'UTF-8'
[INFO] 17:12:33.466 19/231 files analyzed, current file: /home/jenkins/workspace/torservice_temp_jenkinstest-JHGJFDJ3NKMRDAXZBOCEGNRKX2SUYVXPNSYOH4DAWJ7M6OZB7NFA/src/main/java/com/company/controls/DataExportController.java
[INFO] 17:12:43.510 19/231 files analyzed, current file: /home/jenkins/workspace/torservice_temp_jenkinstest-JHGJFDJ3NKMRDAXZBOCEGNRKX2SUYVXPNSYOH4DAWJ7M6OZB7NFA/src/main/java/com/company/controls/DataExportController.java
[INFO] 17:12:53.532 19/231 files analyzed, current file: /home/jenkins/workspace/torservice_temp_jenkinstest-JHGJFDJ3NKMRDAXZBOCEGNRKX2SUYVXPNSYOH4DAWJ7M6OZB7NFA/src/main/java/com/company/controls/DataExportController.java
[INFO] 17:13:03.534 19/231 files analyzed, current file: /home/jenkins/workspace/torservice_temp_jenkinstest-JHGJFDJ3NKMRDAXZBOCEGNRKX2SUYVXPNSYOH4DAWJ7M6OZB7NFA/src/main/java/com/company/controls/DataExportController.java
[INFO] 17:13:13.535 19/231 files analyzed, current file: /home/jenkins/workspace/torservice_temp_jenkinstest-JHGJFDJ3NKMRDAXZBOCEGNRKX2SUYVXPNSYOH4DAWJ7M6OZB7NFA/src/main/java/com/company/controls/DataExportController.java
[DEBUG] 17:13:23.487 'src/main/java/com/company/controls/MappingConstants.java' generated metadata  with charset 'UTF-8'
[INFO] 17:13:23.570 20/231 files analyzed, current file: /home/jenkins/workspace/torservice_temp_jenkinstest-JHGJFDJ3NKMRDAXZBOCEGNRKX2SUYVXPNSYOH4DAWJ7M6OZB7NFA/src/main/java/com/company/controls/MappingConstants.java
[DEBUG] 17:13:31.351 'src/main/java/com/company/controls/WarehouseLocationMapper.java' generated metadata  with charset 'UTF-8'
[INFO] 17:13:33.583 21/231 files analyzed, current file: /home/jenkins/workspace/torservice_temp_jenkinstest-JHGJFDJ3NKMRDAXZBOCEGNRKX2SUYVXPNSYOH4DAWJ7M6OZB7NFA/src/main/java/com/company/controls/WarehouseLocationMapper.java
[INFO] 17:13:43.607 21/231 files analyzed, current file: /home/jenkins/workspace/torservice_temp_jenkinstest-JHGJFDJ3NKMRDAXZBOCEGNRKX2SUYVXPNSYOH4DAWJ7M6OZB7NFA/src/main/java/com/company/controls/WarehouseLocationMapper.java
/home/jenkins/workspace/torservice_temp_jenkinstest-JHGJFDJ3NKMRDAXZBOCEGNRKX2SUYVXPNSYOH4DAWJ7M6OZB7NFA@tmp/withMavenbf77c39b/mvn: line 3: 31914 Killed                  /home/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/M3/bin/mvn --global-settings /home/jenkins/workspace/torservice_temp_jenkinstest-JHGJFDJ3NKMRDAXZBOCEGNRKX2SUYVXPNSYOH4DAWJ7M6OZB7NFA@tmp/withMavenbf77c39b/globalSettings.xml --batch-mode --show-version "$@"
[Pipeline] }
ERROR: [withMaven] WARNING Exception parsing the logs generated by the Jenkins Maven Event Spy /home/jenkins/workspace/torservice_temp_jenkinstest-JHGJFDJ3NKMRDAXZBOCEGNRKX2SUYVXPNSYOH4DAWJ7M6OZB7NFA@tmp/withMavenbf77c39b/maven-spy-20170918-171153-788.log, ignore file.  Please report a bug associated for the component 'pipeline-maven-plugin' at https://issues.jenkins-ci.org 
ERROR: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 393; columnNumber: 202; XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
[Pipeline] // withMaven
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build)
Stage 'Build' skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
[Bitbucket] Notifying commit build result
[Bitbucket] Build result notified
ERROR: script returned exit code 137
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: This error is coming from the XML plugin. What happens if you uninstall it, or if you exclude **/*.xml from analysis?

Comment: thanks for the input, i did not think about the sonar plugins yet. But uninstalling SonarXML did not change this behavior.

Comment: With the same SAXParser error? If so, please [edit] your question to include at least the first few lines of any stacktrace, as well as the first few lines of any 'Caused By' clause (found toward the bottom of the stacktrace).

Comment: I've edited my question with all the relevant output i get, unfortunately no error stack trace for all i can see. the line: "/home/jenkins/workspace/torservice_temp_jenkinstest-JHGJFDJ3NKMRDAXZBOCEGNRKX2SUYVXPNSYOH4DAWJ7M6OZB7NFA@tmp/withMavenbf77c39b/mvn: line 3: 31914 Killed" indicates where the OS kills the process because it ran out of memory and swap... this happens mid-analysis it seems.

Comment: Could you also add your SonarJava version, please? Found in Administration > System > Update Center. BTW, we're close. :)

Comment: Sure, its on version 4.13.0.11627. I've added it to the 'versions running' section. Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: Can you make sure your question is edited to fully represent the current status? For instance, you're not getting the SAXParser error any longer, are you?

Comment: The question is up to date, as you can see in the debug output, the error message is still stating "ERROR: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;"

Comment: That's the Jenkins error? In fact it looks like the problem is (may be) with the analysis of `WarehouseLocationMapper.java`

Comment: I've excluded WarehouseLocationMapper.java (and any files that caused a "Could not complete symbolic execution" debug message) from the test just to be sure, but it still fails the exact same way. It seems arbitrary at which step (file) of the analysis the memory is full and the process fails. Sometimes it manages to analyze 21/231 files, sometimes 54, so i don't think there's one file is causing jenkins/sonar to take up all 20gb of memory plus 20gb of swap, something in the analysis process must be leaking..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We experienced the same problem but after downgrading our jdk from java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.144-0.b01.el7_4 to java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.141-2.b16.el7_4.x86_64 it started to work as expected again. I haven´t look much more into what differs them but we got it up and running again on RHEL-7.4

Comment: Thanks! This seems to have fixed it for us as well. After the downgrade to java 1.8.0.141 the memory usage during sonar scan is back to normal and thus the jobs finish successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue was experienced by me with maven running a sonar analysis in bamboo.
I have confirmed that upgrading the java JDK to 1.8.0.151 resolves the code 137 errors. So if you don't want to downgrade to 1.8.0.141 from 1.8.0.144 try this.